# php set the time in the date function

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

Hopefully this is an easy one, but I am having trouble getting a predictable result. The reason I want it is to add a comparable time to a mongo database that will store in seconds but print to the screen in a formatted time string, as well as print the time + duration as a formatted time string. In the example below it should be 8:30am for the start time and 10:30am for the end time

```
<?php
function toTimeStamp($time){
    // 60 * 60 * 8.5
    // sec * min * $time
    return 60 * 60 * $time; 
}

function fromTimeStamp($sec){
    return date('g:ia', $sec); // HH:MMam/pm
}

$start = toTimeStamp(8.5); // 30600
$duration = toTimeStamp(2); // 7200
echo fromTimeStamp($start) . '<br>'; // 9:30am
echo fromTimeStamp($duration) . '<br>'; // 3:00pm
echo fromTimeStamp(($start + $duration)) . '<br>'; // 11:30pm
```

thanks for looking.

Comment: Are you sure you are using milliseconds? Looks like seconds to me.

Comment: yeah, sorry that's a typo.. php seems to use seconds in the date() funciton. I'll fix it up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like time zone issue to me.
Try this:

```
function fromTimeStamp($sec){
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    return date('g:ia', $sec); // HH:MMam/pm
}
```

According to http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php:

date_default_timezone_set — Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

So you can place the command to a more convenient place to not be called every time.

Comment: brilliant, that was the issue, thanks for your help @mirelon.

Comment: I'm not sure I need to do that as the functions will be methods in a class that save()'s and find()'s on the mongo database. I won't need the method's anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes date function takes second arguments as timestamp(seconds)

Comment: thank's for clearing that up, but that's not the issue the issue is setting the utc time. It sort of works if you use `(60 * 60 * ($time -1))` but it doesn't work when adding the duration to the start.

Comment: Yes there are function for timezone in php. whatever timezone you want you can set that up with date_default_timezone_set(TIMEZONENAME); you can see all the possible timezone on php.net